# How to generate random variables that are exponentially distributed with average 1/lambda (in C++) ?? is it correct?

Tags: c++, random, distribution, exponential

please I need some help..
I need a function in C++ that generates random numbers in exponential distribution with rate lambda per unit time, that is :
f(t)= lambda * exp (- lambda * t) ,  where t>=0

second question: how can I make all these generated numbers from 0 to 1500 for example ??

here is what I have tried to use..

thank you in advance ..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

double ran_expo(double lambda) {
double u;
u = rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0);    
return -log(1 - u) / lambda;     // is this correct?? 
}

int main() {
double lambda = 0.0002; const int N = 500; double tT[N];
srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
tT[i] = ran_expo(lambda);
}
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
tT[i] = tT[i] + ran_expo(lambda);
cout << "tT=" << tT[i] << "\n";
}
}
```

Comment: [`std::exponential_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/exponential_distribution)?

Comment: Yes, that's one way to do it. I agree with @Brian though, why implement your own when there's a standard library implementation?

Comment: thank you so much that was helpful .. but now the problem is ..  how to change the max???  .. the numbers are very large because the max is Inf .. I need random numbers between 0 and 1500 exponentially distributed with average lambda (lambda is 0.0002)  .. can you please help me get the exact code for it ??

Comment: @Ola You can't control the max. You can give it a higher rate value (lambda) so the likelihood of getting large values is small, but you can't guarantee no values over 1500. Alternatively, you can generate a truncated exponential by calculating the probability p of exceeding 1500 with the specified lambda, then generating `u` values between 0 and 1-p for your inversion. Note that this will shift the mean.

Comment: @pjs That is what I will try to do .. Thank you so much again